# Client tools for Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a new project working with an existing oracle database. I've always been a SQLServer guy, so first time with Oracle.

Any recommendations for a [SQLServer Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961) type app for Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toad](http://www.toadsoft.com)

Answer (score 7):

I would start with [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).  It's a client app so you can see your tables, run queries, etc.  It's free, fast and will get you started.

(It's not as good as toad, of course)

Comment: I actually prefer SQL Developer to Toad.  I wouldn't call it "fast" though!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pl/sql developer: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html?gclid=CJLCqNrIz5kCFYQ-3godM3Pmug

Answer (score 0):

I personally like Toad the best but I know many people who prefer SQL Developer. Definite pros and cons to both but like a lot of things it comes down to what you are used to. I haven't used the freeware version of Toad much but I've heard it's somewhat lacking. In my opinion, if you have money to spend go with Toad, if you are looking for something for free go with SQL Developer.